# Why did Snape say ,"There will be no foolish wand waving or silly incantations in this class?"

Tags: harry-potter

Why did Snape say...

> *"There will be no foolish wand waving or silly incantations in this
>   class?"*

if all potions needed "a wave of wand" in the end?

It even confirms this on on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/potions)

> It is often asked whether a Muggle could create a magic potion, given
>   a Potions book and the right ingredients. The answer, unfortunately,
>   is no. **There is always some element of wandwork necessary to make a
>   potion** (merely adding dead flies and asphodel to a pot hanging over a
>   fire will give you nothing but nasty-tasting, not to mention
>   poisonous, soup).

Comment: I think he means *ostentatious* wand-waving

Comment: Ignoring that Pottermore quote, is there any evidence in the original works that wands are actively used in potion-making?  I recall wands being used to clean up afterwards, but that's about it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Yes, but it doesn't matter. Rowling wrote that Pottermore article, so it is canon.

Comment: @amflare, not *as* canon as the stuff that was actually in the books, IMO.  But in any case, the Pottermote quote is vague enough to potentially be subject to interpretation; for example, perhaps merely having your wand present is enough to make a potion, and you don't actually need to do anything specific with it.  Perhaps you do have to use it, but you just touch it to the potion rather than needing to wave it.  If there are potion-making scenes involving wands, they might clarify things.

Comment: Picture a woodworking class in which the instructor says "there will be no foolish saw-waving in this class." Makes sense, right? It's just like that.

Comment: It's possible that the first year potions don't need wand work. Maybe the first year potions are relatively simple & even a muggle could cook them up if needed.

Answer (score 10):

## Snape is trying to challenge the erroneous expectations of his students.

As others have said, Snape isn't trying to say that there is *no* wandwork involved in Potions. He's challenging the assumption that many of his students (and the readers) may have that magic is all about waving a wand about. He's pointing out that, as is the case with subjects like Divination and Care of Magical Creatures, being good at spellwork will only get you so far.

Potions utilises spells, as every branch of magic does (I would hardly have expected them to create the fires for their cauldrons by hand). But it is much closer to cooking or chemistry than Charms or Transfiguration insofar as it involves understanding the mechanics of raw materials and how different substances interact. Snape is effectively saying, "*Don't just wave your wand randomly about and expect to be good at Potions*".

The extended quote is helpful here:

> "As there is little foolish wand-waving here, **many of you will hardly believe this is magic.** I don't expect you to appreciate the beauty of the softly simmering cauldron with its shimmering fumes, the delicate power of liquids that creep through human veins, bewitching the mind, ensnaring the senses..."
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 8, The Potions Master)*.</sub>

Snape's focus is on addressing his students' *expectations of Potions* rather than saying that there was no wandwork involved per se.

By the way, the quote in the question is from the film, not the book. The film speech missed out most of the details from the book. So someone who's watched the movies but not the books may miss Snape's central point: that Potions is just as legitimate as other branches of magic, just a great deal more subtle.

Why would Snape have to make this point? Because many of the kids, especially the Muggleborns, actually think that a magical education consists of randomly waving your wand about. Harry, for instance, was totally clueless about the kind of magic that was expected of him.

> Harry quickly looked down again as Professor McGonagall silently placed a four-legged stool in front of the first-years. On top of the stool she put a pointed wizard's hat. This hat was patched and frayed and extremely dirty. Aunt Petunia wouldn't have let it in the house.
>   Maybe they had to try and get a rabbit out of it, Harry thought wildly, that seemed the sort of thing...
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 7, The Sorting Hat)*.</sub>

It wasn't only the Muggleborns who didn't know much about magic. Even kids from wizarding families wouldn't necessarily know much about Potions.

> Harry was relieved to find out that he wasn't miles behind everyone else. Lots of people had come from Muggle families and, like him, hadn't had any idea that they were witches and wizards. There was so much to learn that even people like Ron didn't have much of a head start.
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 8, The Potions Master)*.</sub>

Snape therefore sets aside some time to clarify what Potions is *actually about* in order to clear up any misconceptions.

Comment: I am late :( that's what i get for furiously typing on my phone without checking if there are other answers ... i'll be deleting mine as they're practically the same, but yours is more coherent :)

Comment: @Morrigan Man, I've been there. I like your answer too, though.

Answer (score 0):

Chemistry can be dangerous even without relying on pronunciation & gestures made while conducting it, so it's for students' protection, to make sure they don't accidentally combust, poison, or otherwise inconvenience themself or others. Snape never had any teaching assistants mentioned, so he can't personally correctly all miatakes instantly, so he takes measures to ensure his students take adequate safety precautions. He was fine with wand-waving if the students followed his instructions, but did not want them to disobey his carefully planned instructions and wave their wands carelessly, which could have disastrous consequences, it was just a safety precaution, like the rule about not using magic in the corridors.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question, which has to do with wandwork specifically.